# Array with selectItemAtIndexPath of a UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm trying to programmatically select cells in a UICollection view. I'm new to Obj-C and I'm not quite sure how to use the selectItemAtIndexPath property. I can grab an array of the images the user has previously selected. It is just an array of numbers corresponding to named images. But I'm not sure how to use that information with selectItemAtIndexPath.

I've looked for examples of someone using

```
- (void)selectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated scrollPosition:(UICollectionViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition
```

But I'm not sure how to use it with my UICollectionView so I can have the right cells selected when the view loads and thus be highlighted. I have multiple selection on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `selectItemAtIndexPath:` for each cell you want to highlight, like so:

```
[self.collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:path animated:NO scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone]
```

Note that for one item (and one only!) you probably want to set the animated property to `YES` and provide a scroll position (one item only because otherwise you're going to be making a *lot*  of needless animation calls).

You'll first need to get the index paths of the cells you want to select. The index path consists of two numbers: the *section* the cell is in and the *row number* (or order, if your collection view doesn't have rows) of the cell inside that section.

If you store the index paths of the cells the user has selected in an array then you can just iterate through. Otherwise you'll need to find the index path out, using a `UICollectionView` method such as `indexPathForCell`.

Comment: Thanks. I think that will help me out a lot.

Comment: Thanks. That line works. I just don't know the best place to put it. I have a fast enumerator to pluck out the items in my array so I can set  the selectItemAtIndexPath:path part. I'm not sure what executes when. I assume I want to use my enumerated block outside of anything setting up the collectionView.

What is the best place to put it?

Comment: The best place is probably to put it in either `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`. If you put it in the latter you'll see the animation, you probably won't if you put in the former.